# Drag and drop a view into a recyclerview

Tags: android

How do i drag and drop a view (not in a recyclerview) into a recycler view at x position?

How do i display a temporary view to show the user where the item will be inserted within the recycler view if they were to drop at their current position?

Should I be implementing prepareForDrop() or something similar to do this? Simple examples will be a great help if possible.

I currently have an ItemTouchHelper to handle the onMove and onSwiped methods for list items already within the recycler view but don't know how to implement dropping a view from outside the recycler view into the recycler view itself.

Thanks